# When running phpcs, ERROR: Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility" does not exist is coming

Tags: php, php-7.1, phpcs, psr-2

I want to run phpcs tool, but this error is coming,

`ERROR: Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility" does not exist`
I ran phpcs -i. That gave me ,

`The installed coding standards are PEAR, PSR1, Zend, Squiz, PSR12, PSR2, MySource and PHPCompatibility.`

But Always this error is coming,
ERROR: Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility" does not exist.
Any reasons ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According currently [PHP Compatibility Coding Standard](https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility#installation-in-a-composer-project-method-1) documentation you need to follow this steps:

1. Open your `composer.json` file and add the following lines to:

```json
"require-dev": {
    "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "*"
},
"prefer-stable" : true,
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "\"vendor/bin/phpcs\" --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility",
    "post-update-cmd" : "\"vendor/bin/phpcs\" --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility"
}
```

2. run `composer update`
3. Test with `./vendor/bin/phpcs -p . --standard=PHPCompatibility`